# How can I use sorting classes by using a Policy and Context class on condition?

Tags: java, list

- Create and implement a Policy class following the below class diagram with a simple configuration mechanism:
- Select MergeSort when the List has more than 10 dates.
- Select BubbleSort when the List has less or equal 10 dates.

So what I've done is extended the class Policy to Context to share the methods.

The variable "dates" is of type `List<Date>`. I made it an array list so I can get the size of it easily.

I used the size method to compare its size to 10 using an if/else function. After, I used the setAlgorithm method to set the type of sort that is required.

```
// Policy Class
import packageName.Context;
import packageName.MergeSort;
import packageName.BubbleSort;
import static java.util.Collections.list;

public abstract class Policy extends Context {
private Context context;
void Policy(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

//You can check the length of the list any time with list.size() 
void configure() {

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dates)) { 
//gives me cannot find symbol for CollectionUtils
        if(dates.size() > 10) {
            setSortAlgorithm(MergeSort); 
//gives me cannot find symbol for MergeSort
        } else if(dates.size() <= 10{
            setSortAlgorithm(BubbleSort);
//gives me cannot find symbol for BubbleSort
        }
    } else {
    }
}
}



//Context Class
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Context implements SortStrategy {
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
SortStrategy sortAlgorithm;

List<Date> getDates(List<Date> dates) {
    return dates;
}

void setDates(List<Date> dates){
    this.dates = dates;
}

void setSortAlgorithm(SortStrategy sortAlgorithm){
    this.sortAlgorithm = sortAlgorithm;
}

SortStrategy getSortAlgorithm() {
    return sortAlgorithm;
}

void sort(List<Comparable> input) {
    performSort(input);
}
}


//MergeSort Class
import java.util.List;

public abstract class MergeSort implements Comparable<SortStrategy> {
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void performSort(List<T> input) {
    mergesort(input, 0, input.size() - 1);
}

// Recursive mergesort method
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergesort(List<T> input, int low, int high) {
    if (high - low < 1) return;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    mergesort(input, low, mid);
    mergesort(input, mid + 1, high);
    merge(input, low, mid, high);
}

// Merge method
// Here we need to allocate a new array, but Java does not allow allocating arrays of a generic type
// As a work-around we allocate an array of type Object[] the use type casting
// This would usually generate a warning, which is suppressed
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(List<T> input, int low, int middle, int high) {

    Object[] tmp = new Object[high - low + 1];
    int leftIndex = low;
    int rightIndex = middle + 1;
    int wholeIndex = 0;
    while (leftIndex <= middle && rightIndex <= high) {
        if (input.get(leftIndex).compareTo(input.get(rightIndex)) <= 0)
            tmp[wholeIndex] = input.get(leftIndex++);
        else
            tmp[wholeIndex] = input.get(rightIndex++);
        wholeIndex++;
    }
    if (leftIndex <= middle && rightIndex > high) {
        while (leftIndex <= middle)
            tmp[wholeIndex++] = input.get(leftIndex++);
    } else {
        while (rightIndex <= high)
            tmp[wholeIndex++] = input.get(rightIndex++);
    }
    for (wholeIndex = 0; wholeIndex < tmp.length; wholeIndex++) {
        input.set(wholeIndex+low, (T) (tmp[wholeIndex])); 
// this is the line that would generate the warning
    }
}
}


//Bubble Sort Class
import java.util.List;

public abstract class BubbleSort implements Comparable<SortStrategy> {
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void performSort(List<T> input) {

    for (int i = input.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (input.get(j).compareTo(input.get(j + 1)) > 0) {
                T temp = input.get(j);
                input.set(j, input.get(j + 1));
                input.set(j + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }

}


}
```

[UML Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYPnC.png)

Comment: You can check the length of the list any time with list.size().

Comment: You've thought of doing something -- why not try it and see? If you have questions then provide this as a [mcve] and we can all stare at it.

Comment: @jdv I did try, but thank you for providing a way to ask in a more beneficial way.

Comment: @IhabBaghdadi see [ask]. The expectation is that question will contain everything necessary to answer, and that includes a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
    if(list.size() > 10) {
        mergeSort(list);
    } else {
        bubbleSort(list);
    }
}
```

To explain it: as soon as you don't have an empty or a null list, you check the number of elements using list.size(). Depending on that, you either use mergeSort if the length is grater then 10, either bubbleSort